# Win32 API Certificate CRL-ONLY revocation check

Tags: c#, winapi, ocsp, certificate-revocation

I need to perform certificate revocation checks.
The user must be allowed to select either OCSP-**only**, CRL-**only**, or both.
The project is using C#, but .NET does not offer independent OCSP/CRL checks out-of-the-box.

By default, Windows first checks OCSPs and if OCSP servers are not accessible, only then checks CRLs. For details:

- [Windows XP: Certificate Status and Revocation Checking](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4954.windows-xp-certificate-status-and-revocation-checking.aspx)
- [How Certificate Revocation Works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee619754(v=ws.10))
- [Managing OCSP Settings with Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee619786(v=ws.10))

This is not what must be implemented, and the requirements cannot be changed.

Win32 API apparently allows to perform certificate revocation checks using OCSP-**only**:

- [CertVerifyRevocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377167(v=vs.85).aspx) with CERT_VERIFY_REV_SERVER_OCSP_FLAG
  enabled.

I don't see any similar option for CLR-**only** checks.

The only way to do it, as I see it, would be to use

- [CryptGetObjectUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380080(v=vs.85).aspx) to extract CRL urls
- [CryptRetrieveObjectByUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380269(v=vs.85).aspx) to download the CRLs
- [CertVerifyCRLRevocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377164(v=vs.85).aspx) to perform the verification

**Question:**

Is there any other **easier** way to perform CRL-**only** checks using Win32?

**Note:**

Third party libraries like Bouncy Castle for e.g. do not do everything that Windows does for revocation checking and I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

That's why I would stick to the Win32 methods since they already handle many things: delta CRLs, stapled OCSP, caching, timeouts, retries, configurability etc.

Comment: The only reason against crypt32.dll is cross-paltform support. If you don't mind (at the moment) about your code support in other operating systems, then I Win32 is ok as long as it solves your task.